# Why can't we call procedure from sql

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I know we can call the function from SQL if it doesn't contain out parameter or DML(except autonomous). But we can't call the procedure from SQL in any condition.
What is the reason for it?
Why can't we call the procedure from SQL? Any specific reason.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of a use case you have in mind, which would benefit from calling a procedure from within an SQL statement?

Comment: I know in real world environment it is not useful. I have been asked this question in interview in mastercard,

Comment: I would assume the interviewer wanted you to say something like  *"a select statement is supposed to return a query result, but if we allow a select statement to run a dml(update/delete/insert) by calling a procedure, the whole purpose of saying that a select statement does not  modify a table would be meaningless"*.  Now, if you ask why again you should say *"That's what the people designing  the procedural languages thought  while implementing it and that's an ANSI standard"* .Going further down the road, it becomes a question of History and not SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
call dbms_output.put_line('Hello')
```

[`CALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CALL.html) is part of the SQL language.

Or we can embed a procedure in an inline function:

```
with function f (p varchar2)
        return varchar2
    as
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
        return p;
    end f;
select f('Demo')
from   dual
```

If you mean a `SELECT` statement specifically, I can't see how you expect that to work. What result set would you expect a query like this to return?

```
select dbms_output.put_line('Hello')
from   dual
```

or

```
select dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, table_name)
from   user_tables
```

This isn't an arbitrary restriction by some standards committee. It just doesn't make any sense semantically.

Comment: Suppose procedure name is p1(). then can you write    select p1() from dual?  I think no.  but my question is why?

Comment: I already covered that exact case with the example of `select dbms_output.put_line('Hello') from dual`, and I asked *'What result set would you expect a query like this to return?'*

Comment: select dbms_output.put_line('Hello') from dual will not work in Oracle. I have run and checked it.

Comment: I know. So what?

Comment: My dear sir, you dint get what I am asking. I have been asked in an interview why we cant call procedure from standalone select query  like we can do in function. Suppose f1() is function then we can write select f1() from dual; but if p1() is procedure we cant do select p1() from dual; . how oracle restrict procedure from getting called from procedure. And why we are not able to do it.

Comment: @OnkarTiwari my point is that there is nothing a `select` statement can possibly do with a procedure, whether that procedure is named `p1` or `dbms_output.put_line` or anything else. The whole purpose of `select` is to report results, and a procedure doesn't have any, so it's impossible to `select` it.

Comment: Again the question is why? Anyways thank you for your kind help @williamRobertson

Comment: Are you asking why it is logically impossible for a `select` statement to report something that doesn't have a value to report?

Comment: For @user9892866 and future readers - because function return some values, but procedure doesn't

Comment: @Yuri I already mentioned that in some detail in my answer. I think user9892866 will be along in a minute to ask why that matters, though.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the [SQL ANSII standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) specifies that only functions can be used in the SQL query.
ISO committee members did not define the use of procedures in SQL queries.

Comment: I'm not sure that really answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call or execute a procedure easily in SQL. Both parametrized or non can be called.

`EXEC dbo.procedure_name`

Comment: `exec` is not an Oracle [SQL command](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm)

Comment: Ok, I thought about SQL Server only.

Comment: The question was tagged with `sql` (which refers to standard SQL) and `oracle`. SQL Server never was part of the question

Comment: SQL Server documentation seems to blur the line between the SQL language and T-SQL extensions such as `print` and `kill`, so I'm not sure whether `exec` is specifically part of the SQL language in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, that you are asking about calling procedures from within other SQL statements (not just call a procedure on its own, which is obviously possible).

Why? That's a matter of opinion, and you would have to ask Oracle DB architects for a real cause.

It would seem, that introducing procedure calls into all possible SQL statements, would bring both syntax and implementation complexity, while not necessarily bringing much more value. Usually there are alternatives, which are not much harder to use, while allowing the same outcome.

In case of a query (a `SELECT` statement), the result should be a data set, and no changes in the database state (data or structure) should be done. A PL/SQL procedure does not return a data set, and can change the database state.

If you are in a situation, where the procedure call is needed to prepare the data, you'd like to query, then you have the possibility to call the procedure first, and then query the database.

You can also write a procedure, which will have an output parameter of a cursor reference, which will effectively give you a query result. (For an ad hoc case, you could use parameterized anonymous PL/SQL block.)

You can also write a tabular function, where you can do complex data processing, using PL/SQL, and return a data set. Such function can be used in a query.

If you are asking also about other types of SQL statements, then you can always call DML (`INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` / `MERGE`), DDL (`CREATE` / `ALTER` / `DROP`) or DCL (`GRANT` / `REVOKE`) from a procedure or an anonymous PL/SQ block, that does those and allows you to mix PL/SQL logic in. No need to do this the other way (introducing PL/SQL into DML / DDL / DCL).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a FUNCTION is used to compute and return the result which is ideal to be invoked from a SQL Query statement or from another FUNCTION or Stored-Proc. Unlike a FUNCTION, a Stored-Proc is used to execute logic/process blocks that may require transaction controls and parameter handling that is not suited for a plain SQL but for a client/application.